# In Elastalert schedule interval option is missing

Tags: kibana, elastalert

In Kibana watcher alerts it's possible to fully control the alert schedule using trigger.

```
{
  "trigger": {
    "schedule": {
      "interval": "2m"
    }
  },
```

However in elastalert  there is no dedicated feature but only to use which aggregate alerts and send

```
aggregation:
  hours: 2
```

There is an open issue https://github.com/Yelp/elastalert/issues/1895
If someone know any viable way or an hack to solve this , please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In ElastAlert v0.2.2, they have provided a limit_execution feature. In that we can define  a cron expression. Since I wanted to run at every 15 minutes , I used 0/15 * * * *.

```
 limit_execution: "0/15 * * * *"

Further reading-
 Refer -https://github.com/Yelp/elastalert/issues/492
 Release note-https://github.com/Yelp/elastalert/blob/master/changelog.md
 Free online cron expression validator-https://crontab.cronhub.io/
```